# Veroboard first time

Tags: circuit-design

I have a little veroboard project due couple of days from now and this is my first time encountering veroboard. I have previously worked with breadboards and I understand how pins are connected in those.

My question is, does this veroboard have rails (where multiple pins are connected) or is every pin is individual?

[image: My veroboard 1]

[image]

I have tried looking it up on google, but couldnt find anything that would answer my question. I saw stripboards where whole row is connected but the back of those boards looked different from what I have.

Sorry for asking such a silly question and thank you

Comment: What is "veroboard"? This is "perfboard" (perforated board) with metal-plated holes.

Comment: Thank you. Having a proper name for a part gave me results I was looking for in the first place. As I mentioned I am new to this. I called it veroboard because my professor called it veroboard

Comment: Veroboard is the brand name of the (original) manufacturers of strip board, in which the holes are connected by parallel strips of copper.

Comment: @IanBland, I now recall "vectorboards" (R), who makes a variety of them for decades, https://www.vectorelect.com/prototyping-boards.html , with power rails, and without. The "veroboard" appears to be a "strip board", and not the one shown in OP question.

Comment: Yes, Veroboard was the original stripboard. At least here in the UK it tends to be used as a generic for stripboard like "biro" for ballpoint pens, and sometimes (wrongly) for other prototyping boards like perfboard etc. Proper Vero is stripboard (on a phenolic substrate).

Comment: You can tell simply by looking at the copper side. The connections aren't hidden like breadboards. You can see them right there.

Comment: You can also get breadboard-patterned "veroboards" and you will be able to tell by the copper connections.

Comment: @IanBland - This is the way I've always heard it in the UK, too, but recently I saw a question here where the asker had purchased perfboard that he said was being sold under the Veroboard brand name, so I'm presuming they produce both types.

Comment: Yes, they do a range of products. Kind of like if the biro company made pencils as well, they'd be Biro pencils, but "a biro" would still be a ballpoint pen. :)

Comment: btw, you can get blank pcb with a universal breadboard pinout (rows and cols of pre-connected traces)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty much WYSIWYG (What you see is what you get).

In your second image you can clearly see that the copper traces are not connected in rows nor columns. Therefor we can conclude that no, this board does not have any rails anywhere.

If you however want rails on this particular board, then you can just sacrifice some wire and solder it along a couple of copper pads.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a "veroboard". The distinctive property of "veroboard" are strips, which a user can cut to form shorter local interconnects. It looks like this (from Wikipedia),

[image]

The board pictured in the question appears to be a cheap two-layer "perforated board" with metal-plated holes. It has no interconnect between holes. These boards are often called "[vectorboards](https://www.vectorelect.com/prototyping-boards.html)", by the name of manufacturer, who makes them for decades in different form-factors, different pitches (0.050" and 0.100) and combination thereof, including perforated non-plated holes, and attached to variety of card edge connectors.

[image]